# nutritionData.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, api, dictionary

I'm currently working on a nutrition app and I'm trying to get my response to render on the screen by mapping over the response array but I'm getting an error that it is not a function.

```
const [nutritionData, setNutrition] = useState([]);

    useEffect( () => {
        getNutrition();
    }, []);

    const getNutrition = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/api/food-database/parser?nutrition-type=logging&ingr=red%20apple&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`)
        const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data.hints[0].food.nutrients);
        setNutrition(data.hints[0].food.nutrients);
    };

    return (
        <div

      {nutritionData.map(nutrients =>( 
                 <Nutrition calories={nutrients[0]} carbs= 
 {nutrients.nutrients[3]} />
             ))}  
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: and what is the result of ```console.log(data.hints[0].food.nutrients)``` ? Does it display fetched data or undefined?

Comment: this mean `nutritionData` is not an array or empty!

Comment: @adel you can map empty arrays too. The problem is `data.hints[0].food.nutrients`, it's not an array, maybe it's undefined or an Object.

Comment: the data.hints[0].food.nutrients was the problem! I zeroed in too far so I rolled it back to data.hints! Thanks all! I'm only about 6 months in on coding and really apprecaite the help!!

Answer (score 0):

`nutritionData` may be used as an array but its prototype is not `Array.prototype` so you can't use functions like `map()`, `forEach()`...

You can check the comparison `nutritionData.__proto__ === Array.prototype` to figure out.

Hope this can help.